# Dynamic table with .each() method

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a dynamic table by iterating through the `key:value` pairs in a JSON object.

At the moment I have only one pair in the object so my table should have only one table row with two `<td>` cells, however I am getting 30+ rows each with two  cells containing `"undefined"` as the text. Not sure what is causing this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="posts">
   <table><h2>Posts from My Leaders</h2>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var gsd = $.post('forumquery_test.php', {'postarray' : postarray}, function(result, success) {              
console.log(result);

var json = $.parseJSON(result); //[{"Username":"stan","Post_txt":"Hi, this is Stan"}]
console.log(json[0].Post_txt); //Hi, this is Stan
console.log(json[0].Username); //stan

$.each(result, function(index, value) {
var username = value.Username;
var posttxt = value.Post_txt;

var newrow = '<tr><td>'+username+'</td><td>'+posttxt+'</td></tr>';
          $('.posts table').append(newrow);
})
})
```

**Result:**

```
Username    Post
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined
etc.,       etc.,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the json datatype to your .post call

```
$.post('url',{data:data},successhandler,"json")
```

Next, remove the `$.parseJSON` line. Profit. You were looping over a string rather than your parsed json, which would explain the 50 rows of undefined you were seeing (there are 50 characters in your json string)

```
var gsd = $.post('forumquery_test.php', {
    'postarray': postarray
}, function (result, success) {
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
        var username = value.Username;
        var posttxt = value.Post_txt;

        var newrow = '<tr><td>' + username + '</td><td>' + posttxt + '</td></tr>';
        $('.posts table').append(newrow);
    })
},"json")
```

Comment: yes, that worked. if i understand, the .post call returned a JSON object and the .parseJSON parsed it to a string, and that was my problem?

Comment: No, you parsed the JSON string that was returned to an object stored in a variable named `json`, but never used it. You instead continued using `result` which was still a json string. If you replaced `result` with `json` where you used `$.each`, your original code would work.

Comment: yes, now I see. that's why it worked for me elsewhere and not here. thanks.